# Cosets for non-homogeneous systems

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, systems-of-equations

I have this problem to solve:

Let $W\subset R^n$ be the subgroup that consists of the solutions of a homogeneous system of linear equations $AX=0$, where $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix. Show that the set of the solutions of a non-homogeneous system $AX=b$, if not empty, is a coset of $W$.

I tried in this way:

I considered these non-empty systems: $AX=b$ and $AY=b$, where $X$ and $Y$ are the solution-arrays: observating that $X-Y=Z$ such that $AZ=0\iff A(X-Y)=0\iff A(X-Y)=b-b=0$, then $X,Y\in \mathbb{L}$, where $\mathbb{L}$ is the same coset of $W$.

Is it correct? If not, could you solv my problem? Please.

Thank you so much

Comment: If $X$ is any solution to $AX=b$ then it is easy to show that the solutions of this system are exactly the elements of the form $X+Z$ where $Z\in W$. (you have to show that all solutions have this form, and also that every element in this form is a solution. Both are easy) In other words, the set of solutions is exactly the coset of the element $X$.

Comment: Thank you! But didn't I proof what you write in (...)?

Comment: Yes, I just explained how to formulate it a bit more clearly.

Comment: Perfect! Thx. Hence, each solution $Y$ of system $W$ can be written as sum of solutions of $W$, this is, $Y=X+Z, \forall X,Y,Z\in W$ and then $Y\in\bigl(X+Z\bigr)W\equiv \mathbb{L}$, where $\mathbb{L}$ is the coset of $W$, isn't it? Thx again

Comment: No. What I said is, if $X$ is one specific solution, then the set of solutions is exactly $\{X+Z: Z\in W\}$. So $X$ itself is not in $W$. (unless $b=0$ of course)

Comment: Ok thank you. Hence $X+Z$ is a $W$-coset, isn't it?

Comment: No, the coset itself is the set $\{X+Z: Z\in W\}$. $X+Z$ is an element of this set.